# is this "function" a surjective, but not injective function?

Tags: functions

[image]

this would be something like

$f(x)=x$ for $x\leq1$

$f(x)=x-1$ for $x>1$

Would this fullfill "give an example for a surjective but not injective function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ "?

Comment: What do you think? Can you show it's not injective? (Find two elements of $\mathbf{N}$ that map to the same thing). Can you show every element of $\mathbf{N}$ is the image of something?

Comment: What is meant by $\mathbf N$? The natural numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but dont plot a line for a map from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$, that is misleading on the first glance :-) (better plot points to stress the discreteness of $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: what do you mean with discreteness? you mean, that there are only positives AND only "points"? to the points: yes i indeed just forgot that, i somehow thought of $\mathbb{R_0}$

Comment: a set is discrete if the points are "spaced out" the way they are in $\mathbb{N}$, so that there is never a location where they accumulate together. Contrast to $\mathbb{Q}$ or the set $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ neither of which are discrete. Although *away from zero* the second set looks discrete, even having one limit point ruins discreteness,

Comment: @StellaBiderman is it now better displayed? altho, i think the point (1,0) is bad

Comment: As you edited your image, you have 2 crosses above 1 now. according to your function definition only the one with function value 1 is correct, otherwise you do not have well-definedness at 1 and you would not even have a *mapping*.

Comment: @Max ok, so in essence: (i think i got it now) at least one y-value has to be given to two x-values, but not more then 1 x -value can be given to 1 y-value. then i have an surjective, but not injective function? And also to every y, there must exist one x.

Comment: is well-defined a nessecarity in this context? i.e. would simply 2 straight lines with slope 1 (and parallel) be surjective, not injective, and "technically" a function (altho a bad-defined one)

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Since i couldnt edit anymore, i deletet it. Here it is again: The first statement means "not injective" (because at least one y has 2 x) if the second statement were true, that would mean "injective" (because there is just one x for each y) **BUT** you have 2 x's for y=1. (x=1 and x=2) so your function is not injective. surjective means, every y does have at least one x (which is true in your case here).

Comment: graphically "surjective" means, the projection on the y-axis gives the full y-axis, and "injective" means, that you can project the y-axis back to the function graph to get the full graph back. And well-definedness means each x has a y - so the projection of the function-graph on the x-axis gives the full x-axis.

Comment: and the other way around; the projection of the x-axis on the graph gives the full graph.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a function onto $\mathbb{N}$ (as each natural number is accounted for), but it is not one-to-one - notice that that value of $1$ in the range can be attained by setting $x = 1$ or $x = 2$. Hence $f$ is not one-to-one.